# Using multiple attachments through comObject Outlook.Application

Tags: email, powershell

I have a script that goes into SCSM, gets the relevant files from the IR and downloads them properly onto the user's computer. 
Next, I need the script to create an email from the client's outlook application and display it on their screen before sending the email..

Here is the part of the script that does that:

```
$GetFiles = Get-ChildItem "$ArchiveRootPath\$IRID\" 

$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application #| New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage

$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.To = "johndoe@contoso.com"
$mail.Subject = "This is a test [$IRID]"

Foreach($GetFile in $GetFiles)
{
Write-Host “Attaching File :- ” $GetFile
 $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList C:\Temp\SCSM_Archive\$IRID\$GetFile
 $mail.Attachments.Add($attachment)
 }

$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Display()
```

However, when I run the script, I get this error:

```
Attaching File :-  email.eml
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Value does not fall within the expected range."
At C:\Temp\SSWireless Script.ps1:99 char:2
+  $mail.Attachments.Add($attachment)
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

All the variables are checked from the previous part of the script that downloads the files. PS is able to see the files, but cannot attach them to the email. 
I don't want to use the send-message function due to the fact that we will be moving to a cross domain email account and would rather use outlook to create the email itself.

Comment: Not sure what version you're using, but the [`Attachments.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553.aspx) that I find appears to require four arguments.  I also don't know why a COM object would necessarily know what a .Net object is (System.Net.Mail.Attachment).

Comment: I'm using PS2.0 in an enterprise environment and this would be part of a master script used in SCSM tasks.
As for calling a .net when I call a com object, I'm not sure. I've tried a bunch of different variants... Commenting out the $attachment line... but in that case, I don't get an error and the email appears, but the attachments are missing from the file (although they are in use by PS).

Comment: Interesting, While probably not the exact answer you're looking for, have you attempted to ZIP the contents of the directory and just simply attach the zip? Not exactly sure how large the contents you are planning to email are but thought it would be worth the mention.

Comment: @bundyfx Zip is not an option. It will be flagged and blocked by either our internal mail server, the gateway servers or the recipient servers (The recipients are external to our organization). IF I specify a file name, then it works, and attaches without any issue ie:
    $Getfiles = "File path\filename"
    $mail.Attachments.add($Getfiles)

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. I'm trying to get the hang of it, and am failing apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reference for [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook Attachments.Add method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments.add.aspx) . This confirms that the first parameter (and the only parameter in your case) needs to be a full path to file.

There is no point passing [System.Net.Mail.Attachment] .NET objects to COM interface.

Your code should look something like this:

```
$GetFiles = Get-ChildItem "$ArchiveRootPath\$IRID\" 

$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.To = "johndoe@contoso.com"
$mail.Subject = "This is a test [$IRID]"

Foreach($GetFile in $GetFiles)
{
    Write-Host “Attaching File :- $GetFile.Name"
    $mail.Attachments.Add($GetFile.FullName)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
At this point, even though I knew that passing a .net in a com object made no sense, I had no idea what else to try.
I'll give it try tomorrow at the office!